One word for someone who is Coerced
Is there a word for a person who has been coerced into doing something because he lacked the intellectual wherewithal to evaluate it beforehand?
Context: A lot of fraudulent conversions from traditional religions into organized religions has happened in Asia and Africa, where spurious reasoning of God and Truth was provided to carry out conversion activity and people were coerced into accepting a new religion.
I don't want to use the word victim here, as victim is a very broad word. I am looking for a specific word to reflect this situation?

Very closely related (*at least): more concise word or phrase for people who have been taken advantage of. Plenty of answers, including 'dupe', but lacking the 'because they lacked the intellectual wherewithal to evaluate it beforehand' condition.

Is there one word for being deceived into complying with ... is also *very closely related.

Given the clarification that the people in question were more "tricked" than "coerced", this may be relevant.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Such a person can be called a

dupe noun
someone who has been tricked:
an innocent dupe

From Cambridge Dictionary.

Trickery is nothing like coercion.  A dupe doesn't know their actions are against their best interests.  That said, the question talks about people who "lacked the intellectual wherewithal", so possibly this is what's being sought?

Googling for coercee tells me that applies.
E.g., occurrences with the expected meaning:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/coercion/index.html -- 106 occurrences

https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4020-9160-5_135 -- 5 occurrences

https://uat-rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/coercion/v-1 -- one occurrence


There are many more...

Coercer and coercee make a very tenable combination indeed. Just that it doesn't appear in most English dictionaries :( Even though, it makes perfect sense and people can understand it.

I think "dupe" should be the accepted answer if trickery is the primary component of the coercion, but for the sake of completeness:

Conscript: Someone or something enlisted compulsorily (usually into an army).

Because a person shanghaied or crimped into naval service would be both a dupe (due to the trickery) and a conscript (due to the coercion).
Perhaps we don't know enough about the circumstances of the proposed coercion. An inmate or convict is a coerced person. So, too, a victim and a slave.

Coercion typically involves persuasion by force or the threat of force. "Pay me the fifty large by Friday or your pet dog Sprinkles gets it". I suppose in the case of religion a threat of eternity in a hot sulphurous hellscape could be considered coercion.
If it is persuasion that overcomes rational thinking by making promises or offering a system that gives peace of mind by providing otherwise difficult answers then it could perhaps be described as being beguiled.

...to persuade, attract, or interest someone, sometimes in order to
deceive them :
He was completely beguiled by her beauty.
The salesman beguiled him into buying a car he didn't want.


-1, this doesn't answer the question at all of what to call someone who has had "this thing" done to them, whether "this thing" is called being coerced, or beguiled.

And 'beguiled' could be used as a substantive.

@Vicky. The person is the beguiled. As Clint Eastwood could attest to (from the eponymous movie).

Yes, the person is beguiled, but that’s the word for the person who is beguiled?

@cph_sto That person is the beguiled.

Oh, I was not aware that beguiled could be used as a substantive. Thanks for that.

Within the context you provide, where a person is forced to convert to another religion, they are often the victims of terrorism. Take Boko Haram in Africa as a classic example.
Children are abducted, the girls raped and forced to convert to Islam and marry Muslim men or be made slaves.
Elsewhere in the world adults can face imprisonment and even death unless they recant from their Christian faith and convert to Islam.
The fear of mutilation, abuse, slavery, torture and death is coercion. That makes those poor people victims. They have been terrorised into converting.
You say “spurious reasoning of God and Truth” is responsible for these conversions to a new religion. Do you have any examples to illustrate this claim?  If this is what you mean, then nobody is being coerced, are they? They are being persuaded to convert.  Duped, perhaps.

Well, there's also the fundamentalist Christian thing in LA where there are so many Catholics. And it's not actually terrorism.


There is no such thing happening in India, unless you believe in agenda some media outlets are out there to disseminate. 2. The question was posted to get the appropriate English word, but in the answer section you choose to give political commentary.


@Lambie I am unaware of what might be happening in Los Angeles regarding "fundamentalist" Christians and Catholics. I agree that whatever is going on in America is unlikely to be terrorism. Perhaps certain members of the community are under pressure to conform or simply shut up and keep their beliefs to themselves? I shall Google it.

@cph_sto I have edited my answer to clarify my response to this question and remove any reference to politics. The appropriate English word for the situation referenced in the question is DUPED.
